# capture any aliphatic on keyboard while form is not visible?

Tags: c#, linq

i tried to capture any character from A…Z but i din't got it
i use the global hot key but they just manipulate the **F2**…..**F12** some thing like
this how can i do that ?
i tried :

```
 public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        // register the event that is fired after the key press.
        hook.KeyPressed +=
        new EventHandler<KeyPressedEventArgs>(hook_KeyPressed);
        // register the control + alt + F12 combination as hot key.
        hook.RegisterHotKey(GlobalHotKeys.ModifierKeys.Control | GlobalHotKeys.ModifierKeys.Alt, Keys.F12);
        hook.RegisterHotKey(GlobalHotKeys.ModifierKeys.Control | GlobalHotKeys.ModifierKeys.Alt, Keys.F2);

    }
    void hook_KeyPressed(object sender, KeyPressedEventArgs e)
    {
        // show the keys pressed in a label.
        MessageBox.Show(e.Key.ToString());

    }
```

Comment: Did you just randomly used 'aliphatic', or do you know what it actually means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you should use Global Keyboard Hook to capture key events from inactive or hidden form, you can use [Keyboard Hooks Library](https://globalmousekeyhook.codeplex.com/releases) which simplifies the process a lot, here is  a sample based on mentioned library:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
using MouseKeyboardActivityMonitor.WinApi;

namespace Demo
{
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        private readonly KeyboardHookListener hook=new KeyboardHookListener(new GlobalHooker());

        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            hook.KeyDown += hook_KeyDown;
            hook.Enabled = true;
        }

        void hook_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if(e.Control && e.Alt && e.KeyCode==Keys.F12)
                MessageBox.Show(@"Alt+Ctrl+F12 Pressed.");
        }
    }
}
```

#### Console Sample:

*NOTE: add System.Windows.Forms.dll as reference to your console application*

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using MouseKeyboardActivityMonitor.WinApi;

namespace Demo
{
    internal class KeyboardHook : IDisposable
    {
        private readonly KeyboardHookListener _hook = new KeyboardHookListener(new     GlobalHooker());

        public KeyboardHook()
        {
            _hook.KeyDown += hook_KeyDown;
            _hook.Enabled = true;
        }

        private void hook_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Control && e.Alt && e.KeyCode == Keys.F12)
                MessageBox.Show(@"Alt+Ctrl+F12 Pressed.");

        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            _hook.Enabled = false;
            _hook.Dispose();
        }
    }

    internal static class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            var t = new Thread(() =>
            {
                using (new KeyboardHook())
                    Application.Run();
            });

            t.Start();

            Console.WriteLine(@"press 'C' key to exit application...");
            while (Console.ReadKey().Key != ConsoleKey.C){}

            Application.Exit();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what if i use that one in console ? do you  have any suggestion ?

Comment: technically you can use it in console, however you need to call `Application.Run()` to do UI message pumping or you should implement your own UI message loop handler. I updated the answer with a console example.